# Why is this function returning all zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, return, slice

Folks this is driving me crazy.

I have the following functions defined below
I get the expected result from maskArray() when I pass it anchor='top' or anchor='left', but it returns and all zeros numpy array in case of 'bottom' and 'right'. I thought i got the slicing wrong, so i experimented with the statements mask[-y:,:] = somevalue outside the function and it works so I believe the syntax is right. Not sure what is going on here.
Here are examples of function calls results

```
In [5]: x = np.round(np.random.rand(10,10) * 10).astype(np.uint8)

In [6]: x
Out[6]: 
array([[ 3,  2,  1, 10,  4,  7,  7,  9,  6,  5],
       [ 1,  6,  3,  0,  9,  3,  7,  6,  0,  4],
       [ 4,  2,  5,  3,  4,  7,  6,  2,  0,  3],
       [ 1,  4, 10,  2,  8,  1,  9, 10,  4,  8],
       [ 9,  8,  3,  5,  3,  0, 10,  5,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  9,  8,  6,  1,  3,  7,  4,  9,  3],
       [ 8,  8,  4,  6,  9,  1, 10,  6,  9,  7],
       [ 6,  2,  4,  8,  2,  9,  2,  4,  7,  4],
       [ 7,  9,  2,  6,  9,  2,  6,  8,  7,  8],
       [ 4,  6,  3,  5,  7,  5,  3,  3,  5,  5]], dtype=uint8)

In [7]: maskArray(x,0.3333,'top')
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)

In [8]: maskArray(x,0.3333,'left')
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)

In [9]: maskArray(x,0.3333,'bottom')
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Can any of you see something that I'm not seeing ?

My other questions is : is there a way to make the slicing statement generic for any dimension of np.array ? meaning instead of having an if statement for each expected array.ndim (i.e: [:x,:] and [:x,:,:] )

Cheers

```
import numpy as np

def getChannels(srx):
    try:
        if srx.ndim == 2:
            return 0
        elif srx.ndim == 3:
            return srx.shape[2]
        else:
            return None
    except TypeError:
        print("srx is not a numpy.array")

def maskArray(dsx, fraction, anchor):
    if anchor == 'top':
        y = np.round(dsx.shape[0] * fraction).astype(np.uint8)
        mask = np.zeros_like(dsx)
        if getChannels(dsx) == 0:
            mask[:y,:] = 1
            return mask
        elif getChannels(dsx) ==  3:
            mask[:y,:,:] = 1
            return mask
        else:
            return None

    elif anchor == 'bottom':
        y = np.round(dsx.shape[0] * fraction).astype(np.uint8)
        mask = np.zeros_like(dsx)
        if getChannels(dsx) == 0:
            mask[-y:,:] = 1
            return mask
        elif getChannels(dsx) == 3:
            mask[-y:,:,:] = 1
            return mask
        else:
            return None

    elif anchor == 'left':
        x = np.round(dsx.shape[1] * fraction).astype(np.uint8)
        mask = np.zeros_like(dsx)
        if getChannels(dsx) == 0:
            mask[:,:x] = 1
            return mask
        elif getChannels(dsx) == 3:
            mask[:,:x,:] = 1
            return mask
        else:
            return None

    elif anchor == 'right':
        x = np.round(dsx.shape[1] * fraction).astype(np.uint8)
        mask = np.zeros_like(dsx)
        if getChannels(dsx) == 0:
            mask[:,-x:] = 1
            return mask
        elif getChannels(dsx) == 3:
            mask[:,-x:,:] = 1
            return mask
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: [avoid asking multiple distinct questions in the same post.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask for the negative of a type `uint8` variable, the result overflows, because negative values don't exist for this type:

```
>>> -np.round(10 * 0.3333).astype('uint8')
253
```

Use a signed integer type and it will work as expected:

```
>>> -np.round(10 * 0.3333).astype('int')
-3
```

Comment: not sure if one should expect such behavior though. i thought the uint8 is only for the underlying type and that the indexers are always unisgned int by defintion

Comment: oh never mind now i see it, the problem is in the assignement of y not the slicing. daaah !